# s3cmd 403 Access Denied error on put but not ls

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, s3cmd

I can access s3 using s3cmd on an ec2 instance to do s3cmd ls s3://myc
bucketname but not using 'put' to add a file. It gives a 403 access denied error.

I am using IAM and have group setup to access on the single bucket in question.
Is there something wrong with my policy, I have found posts saying that s3cmd needs the ListAllBuckets privilege but I have allowed all priveleges in this policy so don't see how that could be the problem.

Anyone any ideas how I could work this out?
Policy below:

```
{


 "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1397683550000",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Sorry- issue was exactly the absence of a ListAllBuckets privilege, I should have checked it first- lazy.

Anyone explain why ListAllMyBuckets privilege is not included in the s3:* statement? Very counterintuitive to my eyes.

Comment: It is included but you need the ListAllBuckets on S3 root and your policy was just valid for "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname".